# Path modification

Tags: android, andengine

I want to calculate the new points when the sprite reaches the previous destination within a specific time duration. How can I do this?

For example, instead of calculating the path first, I want to calculate it after that particular duration is finished.

```
PathModifier(bugduration, path, null, new IPathModifierListener() 
{
    public void onWaypointPassed(final PathModifier pPathModifier,final IShape pShape, final int pWaypointIndex) {
        ......
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onPathFinished() {} and create new path after previous is finished. Maybe it's not so good choice, but it works for me.

---

I wrote some code:

```
function go() {
   HashMap<float, float> coords = calcNewCoords();
   path = new Path(2).to(currentPosX, currentPosY).to(coords.get("toX"),coords.get("yoY"));
   time = calcTime();
   petSprite.registerEntityModifier(new PathModifier(time, 
            path, null, new IPathModifierListener() {
       @Override
        public void onPathWaypointFinished(PathModifier pPathModifier,
                IEntity pEntity, int pWaypointIndex) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            rest();
        }
   }));
}


function rest() {
   ....
   go();
}
```

something like that... it is not my real code.. but I have tried with onPathWaypointFinished() and it's works!!!!
There is character in my game which walks random side to random position, than rests and go to another point...

Comment: Hai racoon.. yes i also know that method. problem of mine is old jar That is not supporting onpathfinished() method in listener

Comment: Maybe try: new Path(2).to(currX, currY).to(newX, newY); With only 1 way. and that will be onWaypointPassed(). No?

Comment: i want to calculate the newx,newy after currx,curry is finished

Comment: can you explain detail, what you want to do. Why you need to do that? maybe I didn't understand something... but it's very strange..

Comment: i want to move the sprite with particular length, angle, and time duration for example sprite start from x1,y1 and move to x2,y2 once it reaches x2,y2 i have to calculate the next point.. i m having only one method in my path listener i.e. onwaypointpassed()

Comment: @Racoon.. i cant able to update my jar.. what u suggest me is not supported by my jar..so i tried with asyntask to calculating new points and pass it in onwaypointpassed.. it took some delay and shows me black screen....Is there any other way to do it?